# How to calculate wait time in Unix? (Based on /usr/bin/time)

Tags: time, wait

This is probably the stupidest question, but I can't find anything about it online, and I'm partially on the verge of falling asleep.

Anyway, I'm assuming it's got to do something with taking the total elapsed/wall time, and subtracting both the user and system time. IE, wall time is 10 seconds, system time is 2 and user is 1, meaning wait time is 7 seconds.

I'd love to get a sure-fire answer instead of using/guessing with this one that's based on my gut.

Comment: CPU time can be greater than elapsed time if more than one CPU is executing the code. For example, two processors working 100% for one second will give 1 second elapsed, 2 seconds user CPU.

Comment: The instances that I'm working with indicate otherwise. If that is the case though, is there no general formula? I was told that I can calculate the wait time with the wall time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula appears to be [exactly as you surmised,](http://www.spinellis.gr/codequality/measurement.pdf) with the caveat raised above.

Since `/usr/bin/time` measures its user and system process time in [CPU-seconds](https://serverfault.com/questions/138703/a-definition-for-a-cpu-second) (according to [the documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/1/time)), you'll need to take the number of CPUs able to execute the code into account. For most simple, single-threaded applications, using one CPU as an estimate is reasonable.* In these cases, you can tolerably use CPU time as a substitute for wall clock time.

For others, it depends on the maximum CPU saturation that program is expected to achieve, and that's outside the scope of what `time` can tell you.

---

* Certain processor-level idiosyncrasies with enhanced parallelism and speculative branch execution make this technically inaccurate, but it's otherwise a reasonable estimate.

Comment: Thanks for the link and the thorough explanation!